cython undeclared name not builtin: m
I am building a model with pysb and I am trying to make simulations.
To avoid them to be slow I have installed cython but I get an error message.
This is the code I enter to import my model 
This is the simulation I get
After loading cython extension I type this code to speed up the simulations time and I get the message at the bottom.
I am sure I don't do it properly. Can someone help me out?
I have no clue on what to do

Where were you expecting m to come from?  There's nothing of that name defined in your code; the error message means exactly what it says.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Please post code as [code block]s, not images

Cython in a notebook doesn't have access to variables declared outside its cell. So you'll need to copy your import p531 as m into the %%cython cell (it looks like you forgot to move it or you overwrote it with the Cython magic).
